# How to say I've succeeded against all the odds of someone

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request

Usually a successful person thanks to his wife or parents for his success during a public speaking.

On the other hand, what if someone becomes successful while his spouse/parents always discouraged him, or insult him continuously?

What does he say in such a situation? Something like:

- I've succeeded despite all her discouragements?
- I've succeeded against all discouragements of her.
- I've succeeded against all insulting of her.
- I've succeeded not because of her but in spite of her.

Comment: Your first and fourth options sound fine.  The "succeeded against" options do not sound fine.  I think they are ungrammatical, and they are definitely not idiomatic.

Comment: @stevekeiretsu Thank you for the comment Steve. Then, I'll prefer to use fourth one.